# How to get binary data of syncfusion chartwebcontrol to save to DB?

Tags: asp.net, syncfusion

I have a syncfusion chartwebcontrol in my aspx page and I need to save the the chart to the database in a binary column. I'm not sure how to get the syncfuion control's image into byte form.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `ChartWebControl` as `Image` by using `SaveImage` method, then convert this image to binary data using `Stream` concept and save this binary data in database. You can use `File Stream` class to convert the chart image to binary.

Please refer below code snippet

[C#]

```
this.ChartWebControl1.SaveImage(Server.MapPath("Chart.png"));
byte[] buffer = ImageToBinary(Server.MapPath("Chart.png"));
//Insert the above buffer data to db for chart image binary data
--------------------------------
public static byte[] ImageToBinary(string imagePath)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
    return buffer;
}
```

You can convert binary data back to images, Please refer below code snippet.

[C#]

```
public static Image BinaryToImage(System.Data.Linq.Binary binaryData)
{
    if (binaryData == null) return null;
    byte[] buffer = binaryData.ToArray();
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return Image.FromStream(memStream);
}
```